# Cordova Mobile App's (iOS) configuration for deploying through CLI

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, continuous-integration, azure-devops

I am writing a continuous integration/delivery build phase with which whenever a build is queued, an Ionic/Cordova app is built out from the source repository hosted in TFS and their apk/ipa files pushed to both Google and Apple's stores.

When it comes to iOS, I am having issues configuring my `build.json` in relation with my provisioning profiles. As per Cordova's guidelines ([link](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/)), I am configuring my build.json file to have its `codeSignIdentity` value set to `iPhone Developer` for both debugging and release modes. However, I have no clue how this can work if it is required by xcode to sign in distribution mode in order to upload to the stores. Whenever I set the `codeSignIdentity` value to `iPhone Distribution` I get the error below:

```
MyApp has conflicting provisioning settings. MyApp is automatically signed for development, but a conflicting code signing identity iPhone Distribution has been manually specified. Set the code signing identity value to "iPhone Developer" in the build settings editor, or switch to manual signing in the project editor.
```

If I keep both signing identities set to developer the archive export succeeds, 
but then the iTunesConnect upload FastLane task ([link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsclient.app-store)) fails with the error:

```
"Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning profile included in the bundle com.xxx.yyy [Payload/MyApp.app] is invalid. [Missing code-signing certificate]. A Distribution Provisioning profile should be used when submitting apps to the App Store. For more information, visit the iOS Developer Portal."
```

Whereas if I keep both of the signing identities as developer and specify a previously imported distribution provisioning profile I get the error in the xcodebuild process as follows:

```
error: exportArchive: No profiles for 'com.xxx.yyy' were found
```

build.json file:

```
{
"ios": {
  "debug": {
      "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
      "developmentTeam": "XXXXYYYYZZZZ",
      "buildFlag": [
        "-allowProvisioningUpdates",
          "EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT = YES",
          "ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES=NO",
          "LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = \"@executable_path/Frameworks\""
      ]
  },
  "release": {
      "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
      "packageType": "app-store",
      "developmentTeam": "XXXXYYYYZZZZ",
      "buildFlag": [
          "-allowProvisioningUpdates",
          "EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT = YES",
          "ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES=NO",
          "LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = \"@executable_path/Frameworks\""
      ]
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you do it in local machine?

Comment: Hi @starianchen-MSFT, no it does not complete locally either.

Comment: Do you mean you get the same error in local?

Comment: What're tasks of your build definition? Can you share the detail log on the OneDrive?

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?